# Dynamic form returns KeyError

Tags: django, django-forms, dynamic-forms

So I used the form template for setting dynamic choices that i found [here](http://blog.eliacontini.info/post/41598616573/django-set-select-choices-dynamically-in-forms)

and thus i got

```
   *forms.py*
   class selectForm2(forms.Form):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           choices = kwargs.pop('my_choices')
           super(selectForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields["select_fields"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

and in my views i have

```
form = selectForm2(my_choices = models())
```

where models() is creating tuples, each having a model name and a model table:

```
def models():
    apps = get_app('Directories')
    for model in get_models(apps):
        model_classes.append( (model._meta.verbose_name, model._meta.db_table), )
    return model_classes
```

but when i run it, `my_choices` returns a KeyError at `choices = kwargs.pop('my_choices')`

Comment: Post the complete traceback. Is it really throwing that exception at the `form = selectForm2(my_choices = models())` line, or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I expect that you have multiple instantiations of the form, ie once for GET and once for POST, and you've forgotten to pass `choices` in one of them.

Comment: yes indeed... that was it. i was confused because the debugger mentioned the KeyError was at forms.py not in my views...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in a view, you instantiate the form twice, once for GET and once for POST. You need to remember to pass in `choices` in both instantations.